# Trying to install foundation using compass

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, zurb-foundation

I get the following error when trying to get my project up on my mac.

```
LoadError on line 31 of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb: no such file to load -- zurb-foundation
```

Note I have updated my gems, updated compass to the latest version, updated the foundation gem but I cannot get my stuff to compile. Also I tried creating a new project with the same settings but i get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

What does your include look like? The library itself is just called `foundation`. On all my projects I include the path to my vendor files (usually bower_components) in my importPaths configuration, and include this in my main sass file:

```
@import 'foundation';
```